# How to Verify a Page is loaded Succesully

Tags: perl, selenium-rc

Hi I have one url which will open the Page in XMl format. Now there is no any Style information for the page so when I am trying to use

```
assertTextPresent();
```

for the verification of a text on the page it showing error

```
 Couldn't access document.body.  Is this HTML page fully loaded?
```

Is there any other way to verify The Page is fully Loaded.

I am using Perl Language with Selenium RC.
I am using Open function for launching the page.

Comment: Are you using the ``waitForPageToLoad`` method?

Answer (score 0):

This is not basically a Perl question. Checking whether a page is loaded completely or not is a client side concern and you can use Javascript to tackle this. With AJAX, on XMLHTTPRequest object, check the status code of 4 and response code of 200, you are pretty much done.